# How to call IBAction in UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created one application in that i have one UIButton created programmatically in UITableViewCell file.

Following is code for that.

```
//UITableViewCell.m
//VIDEO DISPLAY BUTTON VIEW 

self.playBtnClick = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 130, 50, 50)];
self.playBtnClick.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.playBtnClick setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:self.playBtnClick];
```

And I have UITableViewController in which i want to use this UIButton playBtnClick in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Following is code where i want to use playBtnClick

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   //Here I want to perform someTask when i pressed plyBtnClick button
 }
```

Comment: your self.playBtnClick in inside the cell or outside the cell

Comment: i have created that play button that will display me in every cell of the table

Comment: then my answer is working fine for you no need of **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: k no need of every cell or u need only one cell

Comment: where is your button action method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)reuseIdentifier withTag:(long)buttonTag{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSLog(@"tag:%ld",buttonTag);

    UIButton *playBtnClick = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 20, 25)];
    playBtnClick.clipsToBounds = YES;
    playBtnClick.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [playBtnClick addTarget:self action:@selector(playBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [playBtnClick setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playBtnClick.tag = buttonTag;
    [self addSubview:playBtnClick];
}
return self;
```

}

```
-(void)playBtnClick:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"cell index:%d",(int)button.tag);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

call like this way

```
TableViewCell *cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier withTag:indexPath.row];
```

//dont forget to add this UITableViewCell.h file

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)reuseIdentifier withTag:(long)buttonTag;
```

Comment: i have separate file for cell and separate file for table. so this is not working for me

Comment: in UITableViewCell.m class you can  add your button. it will work.

Comment: i already have created button in my TableViewCell but i want to use that button on click, there are 10 cell displayed in table so 10 button display me good, but when i click on one of then it will work for defined selectedRows operation

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@protocol CellSelectedDelegate

- (void)CellChecked:(BOOL)value andCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell ;

@end

@interface TreeViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CellSelectedDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In your CustomTableViewCell.m

where you are creating btn

```
 btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
 btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickme:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self addSubview:btn];
 btn.delegate=self;
```

then in CustomTableViewCell.m add function

```
-(void)clickme:(UIButton *)sender
    {
       [delegate Checked:NO];   
    }
```

And in Your UITableViewController.h

```
@interface tableView : UITableView <CellSelectedDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

And in Your UITableView.m

```
-(void)CellChecked:(BOOL)value andCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
   NSLog(@"%@%@",value,cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //Here I want to perform someTask when i pressed plyBtnClick button
 }
```

You cant perform any tasks on a button click in the above method. The above method is a table delegate method and it can only recognises the tap on table cells.

You should have a custom action button method which fires when you tap the button. You should give the tag value to the button, and in your action method compare the sender tag and do your required tasks.